# Spree example app problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I've trying to build sample application as it's wrote [there](http://spreecommerce.com/documentation/getting_started.html), but there is an error:

```
undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0xb0b16b0>
```

Admin interface works fine. What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just followed the spree Getting Started instructions and run into the exact same problem just now.

Turned out that because my Gemfile specified rails 3.0.10, bundler would install spree 0.40.0 which seems to be quite old.

I solved the problem by updating the relevant lines of the  Gemfile like this:

```
gem 'rails'
gem 'spree', '~> 0.60.0'
```

Then when I ran `bundle update` again it installed rails 3.0.9, and following a `rake db:bootstrap` everything started working as per the docs again...

Hope that helps :)